# Wordpress Product Page Change Label From 'Category' to 'Artist'

Tags: php, taxonomy

I would like to add a php snippet to Change Label From 'Category' to 'Artist' on wordpress product pages (alternatively throughout the whole site)

I see many examples of how to remove the label, but no good example or function to rename the label that displays in the product page.

I am posting what I thought was a solution; but I swung and missed.

Ideas?

```
function revcon_change_cat_label() {global $submenu; $submenu['edit.php'][15][0] = 'Artists'; // Rename categories to Artists
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'revcon_change_cat_label' );

function revcon_change_cat_object() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Artist';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Artist';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Artist';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Artist';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Artist';
    $labels->new_item = 'Artist';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Artist';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Artist';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Artists found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Artists found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Artists';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Artist';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Artist';
}
add_action( 'init', 'revcon_change_cat_object' );
```

Answer (score 0):

On a News site, we changed the post taxonomies **Category** and **Tag** to **Departments** and **Topics**. This works in all the screens on the back end; if you're using WordPress's functions [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) or similar, they *should* also be translated on the front end, I believe.

Something like the code below work to change **Category** to **Artist**, assuming you're using the (Post) Category taxonomy. If not, you might need to figure out the name of the taxonomy and adjust the `taxonomy_labels_{$taxonomy}` filter to suit.

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_labels_category', 'wpse418337_rename_taxonomies' );

/**
 * Renames the taxonomy labels.
 *
 * @param  stdClass $labels The taxonomy label set.
 * @return stdClass         The filtered label set.
 */
function wpse418337_rename_taxonomies( $labels ) {
    // Search for these strings...
    $find = array(
        'Categories',
        'categories',
        'Category',
        'category',
    );
    // ...and replace 'em with these strings.
    $replace = array(
        'Artists',
        'artists',
        'Artist',
        'artist',
    );
    foreach ( $labels as $key => $label ) {
        if ( 'name_admin_bar' !== $key ) {
            $labels->$key = str_replace( $find, $replace, $label );
        }
    }
    return $labels;
}
```

**Note:** This code is **untested** and may need customization for your site. Don't test it in production. It's also not i18nized; if you need translations, you'll need to familiarize yourself with WordPress's [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) and related functions.

### References

- [`taxonomy_labels_{$taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_labels_taxonomy/) -- filters the taxonomy labels; the last part, `{$taxonomy}`, is the name of the taxonomy you're editing; I've used `category` but you'll need to make sure you know what taxonomy your installation uses
- [`get_taxonomy_labels()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy_labels/) -- shows the full list of taxonomy labels